# How can I shuffling images using Java NetBeans

Tags: java

So, I design 12 labels and 1 button, and I have a folder contains 12 images; my question is how can I make auto images shuffle from the folder to the 12 labels each time I press the button?? everything working good but the problem the images did not shuffle. I will be so thankful for any help

the code I use is:

```
File file = new File("src/Images");
String[] imageNames = file.list();
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
    Image im1=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/img1.png")).getImage();
    ImageIcon iconLogo1 = new ImageIcon(im1);
    Image im2=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/img2.png")).getImage();
    ImageIcon iconLogo2 = new ImageIcon(im2);
    Image im3=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/img3.png")).getImage();
    ImageIcon iconLogo3 = new ImageIcon(im3);
    jLabel1.setIcon(iconLogo1);
    jLabel2.setIcon(iconLogo2);
    jLabel3.setIcon(iconLogo3);
    ArrayList <ImageIcon> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(iconLogo3);
list.add(iconLogo2);
list.add(iconLogo1);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    }
```

Comment: I Just test the code with 3 images only to see if it will work or not, but the project will contain 12 image

Comment: This Question has already been asked before see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478905/how-to-make-random-pictures-in-java
Hope this helps

Comment: Why are you creating an ImageIcon and then getting the Image from the Icon and then use the Image to create another Icon?

Comment: thank you so much, but I want any way to use the Collections.shuffle(); method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect to see:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(iconLogo1);
jLabel2.setIcon(iconLogo2);
jLabel3.setIcon(iconLogo3);
ArrayList <ImageIcon> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(iconLogo3);
list.add(iconLogo2);
list.add(iconLogo1);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

1. First you add the Icons to each JLabel
2. Then you add the Icons to an ArrayList
3. Then your shuffle the ArrayList

Shuffling the ArrayList has nothing to do with the Icon added to the JLabel, so of course the Icons will always appear in the same order.

If you want the Icons on the labels to be shuffled, then you need to add the Icon to the label AFTER you shuffle the ArrayList.

Something like:

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
jLabel1.setIcon(list.get(0));
jLabel2.setIcon(list.get(1));
jLabel3.setIcon(list.get(2));
```

Of course if you have 12 labels you would not want to write the code manually. You should also add your 12 labels to an Array (or ArrayList) and then write a loop to set the Icon of each label in the Array.